# Repeating annual values multiple times to form a monthly dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an annual dataset as below:

```
year <- c(2016,2017,2018)
xxx <- c(1,2,3)
yyy <- c(4,5,6)
df <- data.frame(year,xxx,yyy)
print(df)
  year xxx yyy
1 2016   1   4
2 2017   2   5
3 2018   3   6
```

Where the values in column xxx and yyy correspond to values for that year.
I would like to expand this dataframe (or create a new dataframe), which retains the same column names, but repeats each value 12 times (corresponding to the month of that year) and repeat the yearly value 12 times in the first column.

As mocked up by the code below:

```
year <- rep(2016:2018,each=12)
xxx <- rep(1:3,each=12)
yyy <- rep(4:6,each=12)
df2 <- data.frame(year,xxx,yyy)

print(df2)
   year   xxx  yyy
1   2016    1    4
2   2016    1    4
3   2016    1    4
4   2016    1    4
5   2016    1    4
6   2016    1    4
7   2016    1    4
8   2016    1    4
9   2016    1    4
10  2016    1    4
11  2016    1    4
12  2016    1    4
13  2017    2    5
14  2017    2    5
15  2017    2    5
16  2017    2    5
17  2017    2    5
18  2017    2    5
19  2017    2    5
20  2017    2    5
21  2017    2    5
22  2017    2    5
23  2017    2    5
24  2017    2    5
25  2018    3    6
26  2018    3    6
27  2018    3    6
28  2018    3    6
29  2018    3    6
30  2018    3    6
31  2018    3    6
32  2018    3    6
33  2018    3    6
34  2018    3    6
35  2018    3    6
36  2018    3    6
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I'm new to R and I can see how I would do this with a loop statement but was wondering if there was an easier solution.

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% uncount(12)` or in `base R` `df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 12),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `df` to a matrix, take the kronecker product with a vector of 12 ones and then convert back to a data.frame.  The `as.data.frame` can be omitted if a matrix result is ok.

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(df) %x% rep(1, 12))
```